# Select rows with max value in column 1 using pipeline

Tags: unix, uniq

I have the following code:

```
cut -f1,3,4 data.txt | uniq --count | sort -k1
```

This produces the following:

```
 1 data data data data 
 1 data data data data
 ...
 ...
 ...
 4 data data data data
 5 data data data data
 5 data data data data
```

I am trying to select the last two rows because they contain the max values in column 1. The now of rows containing the max value in column 1 is subject to change along with the max value itself.

In this case, is there a way I could extract the last two columns using pipe-lining.

```
 5 data data data data
 5 data data data data
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you provide a sample file `data.txt` and indicate what exactly do you want (eg, rows appearing the most, etc)?

Comment: @fedorqui Yes, which rows appear the most.

Comment: Note that if you do `cut -f1,3,4 data.txt | sort | uniq --count | sort -k1 | tail -1` you will get your desired output. Why? Because `sort` before `uniq` makes `uniq` group all matched lines. Hence, `data data data` will appear just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use as below

```
cut -f1,3,4 data.txt | uniq --count |  awk '$1==a' a=`cut -f1,3,4 data.txt | uniq --count | sort -k1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
```

## Explanation:

```
# below AWK will print only line(s) which matches 
# condition $1 equal AWK variable "a" (i.e passed as argument to the command ). 
# Where $1 is first column based on default field separator space 
# Max value of column 1 is passed in this variable "a" as command line argument.  

awk '$1==a' a=<maxvalue_in_column_1>

# To get the max value in column 1, below is used
# command extracts last row (tail -1) from the sorted data (last row will have max value in column 1 )
# AWK is used again to extract first column (max value) from this last line (i.e awk '{print $1}' )
# this command is enclosed in quotes (back tick) operator which will assign its output to variable a 

a=`cut -f1,3,4 data.txt | uniq --count | sort -k1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
```

sample output

```
  3  data data data data2
  3  data data data data3
```

Comment: Hi Narendra. Thanks but I am looking for a more general solution as the number of rows containing the max value is subject to change. The max value may not always be `5` as well. I have edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Giri, I guess the solution is general and will work for any number of lines, try it.

Comment: However, if there were 3 rows containing the max value `5`, I would need to write `tail -3` right? I'm trying to find a solution where I wouldn't need to change this.

Comment: sorry, then misunderstood your requirement...modified the answer

Comment: Thanks Narendra. Do you think you could please explain how ``awk '$1==a' a=`cut -f1,3,4 data.txt | uniq --count | sort -k1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'`` works?

Comment: @Giri, added explanation in the answer.